# SVG to PNG in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, png

I have a problem with converting svg to png(base64).
Svg to base64 works fine, because it displays just fine in the browser.
But when i try to load in the image, it won't load. Anybody might have an idea why?

```
  var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  var svg64 = btoa(xml);
  var b64start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
  var image64 = b64start + svg64;
  console.log(image64);

  const img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    const dataBase64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(dataBase64);

    generatePowerpoint(response, dataBase64);
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    console.log(this.src);

  }
  img.src = image64;
```

Comment: Does an image have the width and height if it's not appended to the DOM yet? Try `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` instead.

Comment: Im not trying to append it to the dom, but get its base64 to my powerpoint builder

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the browser you are using. Using Firefox, the svg tag must have width and height attributes (unit not in %).

It also depends of the content of the svg. If the svg contains non-latin characters, btoa may fail (even if it seems not to be the problem here since Svg to base64 works fine in your case).